# Sum values of the array against same SKU

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting the total sold items from an URL and it return in an array that contains the 'SKU', 'Date', 'Quantity' and 'Total Price'. 
    I want to calculate the Total Quantity against Same 'SKU' and store in new array. 
    Can any one let me know how can i do this in PHP language?

```
$url ="abc";                
<pre>
$post_fields = array();                     
$post_fields['EndDateUtc']=$end;
$post_fields['StartDateUtc']=$start;
$post_fields['TenantToken']=$TenantToken;
$post_fields['UserToken']= $UserToken;          
$data_string = json_encode($post_fields);               
</pre>
<pre>
$curl_header = array();
$curl_header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 180);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$datr = json_decode($output, TRUE); 
print_r($datr);
```

Array Output :
    --------------

`Array
(
    [SoldItems] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SKU] => 8273-Navy-M
                    [Date] => 2017-10-12
                    [Quantity] => 15
                    [TotalPrice] => 7685
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [SKU] => 2879-S-B-White-3XL
                    [Date] => 2017-10-12
                    [Quantity] => 2
                    [TotalPrice] => 298
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [SKU] => 8273-Navy-M
                    [Date] => 2017-10-12
                    [Quantity] => 2
                    [TotalPrice] => 298
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [SKU] => 2262-S-A-Black-2XL
                    [Date] => 2017-10-12
                    [Quantity] => 1
                    [TotalPrice] => 199
                )
        )
)

</pre>

thank you so much.`

Comment: What have you tried? Please add that code too

Comment: Any attempts yet? Have you tried a foreach()?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: i just include the code in the post can you please read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$skuTotal = [];

foreach($items['SoldItems'] as $item) {
    if(isset($skuTotal[$item['SKU']])){
        $skuTotal[$item['SKU']] += $item['Quantity'];
    }else{
        $skuTotal[$item['SKU']] = $item['Quantity'];
    }

}

foreach($skuTotal as $sku => $total) {
    echo "SKU " . $sku . " , Total " . $total." ";
}
```

Comment: I have try this but nothing happened.

Comment: Its working on my end, please confirm you are sing correct variable names

Comment: i have update the question and also include code. can you please read it again?

Comment: Can you pleae use my code and use print_r($skuTotal), to show me the result. Also if you are getting any error please show me that error

Comment: now its working, i just change the variable names. thank you so much for help!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
 Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with something like that, it's untested and may need some adjustment to match your real scenario:

```
$totalsBySku = [];

foreach($soldItems as $sale) {
    $totalsBySku[$sale['SKU']] += $sale['Quantity'];
}

foreach($totalsBySku as $sku => $total) {
        print "SKU " . $sku . " has a total quantity of " . $total;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your latest Question Update you must rename the variable in the first foreach loop: 
`foreach($datr['SoldItems'] as $sale) {`